# How do I calculate dB(A) values for 1/3 octave bands using AVAudioRecorder in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone, avaudiorecorder, decibel

I have used AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioSession which gives me values in decibels in the range 0 (extremely loud) to -160(near silence). In the app, I have to plot an A-rating i.e.dB(A) curve for real time audio measurements received from the iPhone microphone.

I am implementing the following procedure -

1. **Get the dB value from the AVAudioRecorder**

   ```
   NSDictionary* recorderSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4],AVFormatIDKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:44100],AVSampleRateKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                     nil];
   float dbValue = [self.recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]; //which returns a dB value in 0 to -160 range
   ```
2. **Obtain a positive dB value**, float posdBValue = dbValue+160;
   for example, if dbValue=-100, then posdBValue = -110+160 = 50dB
3. Calculate dB(A) values by adding A-weighting for different 1/3 octave frequency bands 
   Reference for A-weighting values  - http://personal.cityu.edu.hk/~bsapplec/single.htm

   - dB(A) for 31.5Hz = 50 -39.4 = 10.6;
   - dB(A) for 40 Hz = 50 -34.6 = 15.4
   - dB(A) for 50 Hz = 50 -30.2 = 19.8
4. Plot the dB(A) values Vs Frequncy bands on the graph

**Questions**
 1. Is this the correct way to find out dB(A) values from decibels?
 2. Is FFT supposed to be used? If yes, where and how does FFT fit into the calculations?
 3. Based on a single dB value returned from *averagePowerForChannel* method, do I have to calculate different dB values for all the center frequencies in 24 Octave bands? If yes, how?
 4. Can anyone suggest a solution, open-source library, references for iPhone code?

I am at a complete loss. I feel I am missing out on something. Please help! I just need to figure out the calculations and logic for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first question about obtaining a dB(A) value by adding an
arbitrary dB value: I think the answer is no, that is not
correct. In digital audio, 0dB is considered a full scale signal
with lower amplitudes going negative.

As for the 1/3rd octave analyzer: Let's start with the definition of an octave. An octave means a doubling or halving of a frequency. So 20Hz and 40Hz are an octave apart. If you divide an octave logarithmically into 3 ranges those are called 1/3rd octave bands.

The job of a 1/3rd octave analyzer is to display in meter form
the level of each of the bands over a given frequency
range. Choosing a range of 20Hz to 20kHz, the first meter you'd
have a bar indicating the level with a center frequency of 20Hz,
a lower band limit of of 17.8 Hz and an upper band limit of 22.4
Hz. And so on up the spectrum.

The most common way this is implemented is with a bank of
bandpass filters, each tuned to one of the center
frequencies. You then take the output from the filter and compute
the RMS and that becomes the level for that band. If you are
doing this in software then there is a fair amount of DSP
knowledge required to design the filters and the computational
overhead is rather high (31 filters to cover 20Hz to 20kHz).

Another approach is to use an FFT. With this approach the goal is
to lump together FFT bins around the center frequency and compute
the total energy. The trick is in choosing which bands to lump
because FFT bins are equally spaced in hertz.

I don't know what sample rate you are recording at but it's
pretty easy to compute what your bin widths and bin centers are
going to be:

The bin width is equal to the sampleRate/FFTlength. A 66536 pt
FFT at 48kHz gives a bin width of 0.73Hz. Bin 24 has a bin lower
limit at 17.58 and a bin center at 17.95, which is reasonably
close to the lower band limit of a 1/3rd octave filter. And bin
30 has a upper limit of 22.71 and a center of 22.34, reasonable
close to 22.4Hz. As you might notice, you are introducing some
amount of error due to the frequency resolution of the FFT. You
can reduce this error by increasing the size of the FFT.

Here's the calculator I used for finding the FFT frequencies and the 1/3 octave filter frequencies: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/audio/calculator.html

Comment: You might want to ask what the frequency response of the device's microphone is.  It's actually pretty flat, surprisingly low when the HPF is disabled, but probably not as low as 17Hz.  It also appears to be consistent between models.

Comment: @marko. Thanks for pointing that out. I was just using 20Hz and its upper and lower bounds as an example mainly because its the first band in a typical 20-20kHz 1/3 octave analyzer.

Comment: From memory, it rolls off at about 30Hz or thereabouts - Apple has applied a fair bit of EQ by this point to achieve this response.

Comment: That was very useful jaket. I am using sampling rate of 44.1Khz with 1024 samples. So I get 512 bins each with a width of 43.0664 Hz. I used the calculator in the reference link to obtain all 512 bins. But how do I lump the bins together to obtain amplitudes at **octave frequencies only** (1/3 octaves not required at this point of time)? And once the bins are lumped, how exactly do I calculate the amplitudes at octave frequencies?

Comment: Selecting the bins is a matter of choosing the ones which are a doubling of frequency. If you're first bin starts at 43Hz and your second bin at 86Hz then that is one octave. The next octave is going to be at 86*2Hz which is the next 4 bins and so on. Calculating the amplitudes should be something like y = rms(abs(bins[a:b]))